# How to use NodeTypeAlias within Umbraco 5

Tags: c#, .net, razor, partial-views, umbraco

Getting error `'Umbraco.Cms.Web.BendyContentList' does not contain a definition for 'Children'`

While trying to use

```
@inherits RenderViewPage
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
@using Umbraco.Cms.Web;
@using Umbraco.Framework;
@using Umbraco.Framework.Persistence;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "FAQs";
    Layout = "Layout.cshtml";

    var accordionTitle = DynamicModel.Children.Where("NodeTypeAlias == \"supportAccordion\"");
    var accordionItem = DynamicModel.Children.Where("NodeTypeAlias == \"supportAccordionItem\"");

}

<section class="support-wrapper">

    <h1>Help & Frequently Asked Questions</h1>

    <section class="questions">

    @foreach (var item in accordionItem)
    {
    <h2>@accordionTitle.title</h2>

        <h3><a href="#">@item.question</a></h3>
        <div>
            <p>@item.answer</p>
        </div> 


    }

    </section><!-- end questions -->

</section><!-- end section wrapper -->
```

I've looked at http://our.umbraco.org/forum/core/umbraco-5-general-discussion/27856-razor-in-Umbraco-5-filtering-child-nodes-by-doc-type But still not working.

My Umbraco tree looks like the following. I've put the Document Type name in Red.

[image]

There's not much documentation out on Umbraco 5 yet as it was recently released. Does anyone know what could be the issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're running on an older release than the RTM, as BendyContentList was removed from the codebase and the code you have should work fine.

Could you check the version you're running? This can be done by checking the About button the top right corner of the backoffice.

Comment: Says "Umbraco v5.0 RC 1 (Assembly version: 5.0.0.16047" and I'm using Bend() in another view just fine.

Comment: Looks like we were using RC1, going to upgrade tonight! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yea! We've done an upgrade and re-factored our code a bit. Works like a charm. It's been hard finding documentation on the RTM though.